# Hiding and showing div, using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

while working on a school project i ran into a problem using javascript to show and hide a couple of divs(five to be exact). I want to be able to open all five and place them on the page using position:absolute and top and left cordinates, since this makes them float on top of my text content i made a seprate div, named wrapper to occupy their space and push the text down. However what seem like a pefect code snippet, isn't. Neither the menu divs named  gs 1 - gs 5 or the occupy div shows up. The thought behind the counter is that if a menu div is oppened counter ++, else (meaning a menu is set as unhidden) the counter is subtracted, and therefor if none is open the counter equals 0 and the occupy should be set as hidden.

```
int count = 0;

function unhide(col2) {

var item = document.getElementById(col2);
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    if (item) 
    {       
        //wrap.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
        item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';  

        if(item.className=='unhidden')
        {
        count++;            
        }
        else if(item.className=='hidden')
        {
        count--;
        }
    if(count > 0)
    {
    wrap.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';  
    }

    }




 }
<a href="javascript:unhide('gs1');">Game Station 1</a>
<a href="javascript:unhide('gs2');">Game Station 2</a>  
<a href="javascript:unhide('gs3');">Game Station 3</a>
<a href="javascript:unhide('gs4');">Game Station 4</a>
<a href="javascript:unhide('gs5');">Game Station 5</a>

</div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="hidden">
        <div id="gs1" class="hidden">       
        </div>

        <div id="gs2" class="hidden">   
        </div>


        <div id="gs3" class="hidden">       
        </div>

        <div id="gs4" class="hidden">       
        </div>

        <div id="gs5" class="hidden">       
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the small css snippet

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; display: none;}
.unhidden { visibility: visible; display: block;}
```

Comment: just for fun, could you `alert(item.className);`  Is this the full code example?  Because if its not, you may have a hard time with `item.className == 'hidden'` since there will be more than one class...

Comment: Curious... can you show us the code that's being output for those divs in question? I'm wondering if by chance they have additional classes on them other than hidden or unhidden. Or for that matter if you're outputting them with no class at all for the start.

Comment: No data is yet being output in the divs, just the css code `#gs1
{
height: 400px; 
width: 192px;
background-color: grey;
left: 384px;
top: 0;

}` its the same for all the 5 divs excluding the number behind the name "gs"

Comment: and yes it is the full code only the javascript tags are left out

Comment: Show us more code.  You could have some errors because of other code that you are not including!

Comment: at Micheal, if i alert(item.className) i get no reacton what so ever..

Comment: what does the error console say?  You should get some sort of alert statement (or an error!)

Comment: The script is most likely erroring out at int count = 0;.  Should be var count = 0;.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/03rGV4jF html code

Comment: Take a look at the jsfiddle in my answer.  It shows a working example.  You have an error in your syntax (int count should be var count).  Also, the code that you posted to pastebin does not have an element with id = "wrapper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the wrapper is being marked as hidden after the div is unhidden.  See my example - http://jsfiddle.net/MYaNb/2/.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in the css

```
.show_hide 
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

Put this in the head of you page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".slidingdiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();
        $('.show_hide').click(function()
        {
            $(".slidingdiv").slideToggle();
        });
     });
</script>
```

Put this in the place where you will show and hide a div

```
<div class="slidingdiv">
   something
</div>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">show/hide</a>
```